# What is the `filter` call for in this string split operation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have a line of legacy code to split a string on semi-colons:

```
var adds = emailString.split(/;+/).filter(Boolean);
```

What could the `filter(Boolean)` part do?

Comment: Can you also add `emailString` value

Comment: I don't understand how this question got two cowardly downvotes, yet the answer it evoked has two upvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`filter(Boolean)` will only keep the truthy values in the array.

`filter` expects a callback function, by providing `Boolean` as reference, it'll be called as `Boolean(e)` for each element `e` in the array and the result of the operation will be returned to `filter`.

If the returned value is `true` the element `e` will be kept in array, otherwise it is not included in the array.

**Example**

```js
var arr = [0, 'A', true, false, 'tushar', '', undefined, null, 'Say My Name'];
arr = arr.filter(Boolean);
console.log(arr); // ["A", true, "tushar", "Say My Name"]
```

---

In the code

```
var adds = emailString.split(/;+/).filter(Boolean);
```

My guess is that the string `emailString` contains values separated by `;` where semicolon can appear multiple times.

```
> str = 'a@b.com;;;;c@d.com;;;;dd@dd.com;'
> str.split(/;+/)
< ["a@b.com", "c@d.com", "dd@dd.com", ""]

> str.split(/;+/).filter(Boolean)
< ["a@b.com", "c@d.com", "dd@dd.com"]
```

Here `split` on this will return `["a@b.com", "c@d.com", "dd@dd.com", ""]`.

Comment: So my new `emailString.split(";").filter(Boolean);` will do the same, and filter out empty strings caused by consecutive semi-colons. Thanks.