# How to split string without getting empty values to the output array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, url

I am using [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to split my string `/value/1`

```
var value = "/value/1/";

var arr = value.split("/");
```

in result I will get an array with 4 elements "", "value", "1", "";
But I really need the nonempty values in the output array.
Is there any way to produce an array base on my input string but array without blank elements?

My string could be `/value/1/` `/value/1` `/value/` `/value` basically I am precessing `http request.url`.

Comment: yeah it is just my wrong formatting here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `match` with regex.

```
str.match(/[^\/]+/g);
```

The regex `[^\/]+` will match any character that is not forward slash.

```js
function getValues(str) {
  return str.match(/[^\/]+/g);
}

document.write('<pre>');
document.write('<b>/value/1/</b><br />' + JSON.stringify(getValues('/value/1/'), 0, 4));
document.write('<br /><br /><b>/value/1</b><br />' + JSON.stringify(getValues('/value/1'), 0, 4));
document.write('<br /><br /><b>/value/</b><br />' + JSON.stringify(getValues('/value/'), 0, 4));
document.write('<br /><br /><b>/value</b><br />' + JSON.stringify(getValues('/value'), 0, 4));
document.write('</pre>');
```

Comment: what does two last params `...0, 4` means in `JSON.stringify()` ?

Comment: @sreginogemoh Those are just for showing results on the page, the parameters are for formatting purpose. You can only use `str.match(/[^\/]+/g);` code to get matches.

Answer (score 19):

Try using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var arr = value.split("/").filter(function (part) { return !!part; });
```

Or the same shorter version as *Tushar* suggested.

```
var arr = value.split("/").filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: If you want to do this way, then use `value.split('/').filter(Boolean);`

Comment: I'd typically use ES6 to make it look prettier, but yeah that's also possible.

Comment: For reference of how `Boolean` passed to `filter` works. [What is the `filter` call for in this string split operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33516569/2025923) and [Get number of non-empty elements from nested arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33802897/2025923)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use String to match a symbol you can try using: `RegExp("/", "g")` - but this is not the best case, if you still want not to match escaped symbol `\` and provide some API for use you can user `RegExp("[^\/]*", "g")` or `/[^\/]*/g`